# Conversor temperaturas en HTML. Ayuda urgente

Tags: javascript, html

debo hacer un programaa en html con componentes javascript que me haga lo siguiente:
Ingresar una temperatura en grados celsius y con un boton convertir que aparezca en dos campos distintos la temperatura en Farenheit y en Kelvin.
Solo me convierte a farenheit, a kelvin no, lo del boton no lo hice por que no se como, si me podrian ayudar estoy muy agradecirdo

Este es mi codigo:

> 

```
<html>
<title>Conversor Celsius a Farenheit/Kelvin</title>
<body>

<h2>Conversor de temperaturas</h2>
<p>Escriba aqui el valor de la temperatura en celcius:</p>

<p>
  <label>Celsius</label>
  <input id="inputCelsius" type="number" placeholder="Celsius" oninput="CelsiusFarenheit(this.value)" onchange="CelsiusFarenheit(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Farenheit: <span id="Farenheit"></span></p>
<p>Kelvin: <span id="Kelvin"></span></p>

<script>
function CelsiusFarenheit(temp) {
  document.getElementById("Farenheit").innerHTML=((temp*9/5)+32);
}
function CelsiusKelvin(temp2) {
  document.getElementById("Kelvin").innerHTML=(temp2+273);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sin el boton es muy dificil hacer lo que quieres.  Con un boton seria asi:

```html
<html>
<title>Conversor Celsius a Farenheit/Kelvin</title>
<body>

<h2>Conversor de temperaturas</h2>
<p>Escriba aqui el valor de la temperatura en celcius:</p>

<p>
  <label>Celsius</label>
  <input id="inputCelsius" type="number" placeholder="Celsius">
  <button onclick="CelsiusKelvin()">Calcular</button>
</p>
<p>Farenheit: <span id="Farenheit"></span></p>
<p>Kelvin: <span id="Kelvin"></span></p>

<script>
function CelsiusKelvin() {
  var temp = document.getElementById("inputCelsius").value;
  document.getElementById("Farenheit").innerHTML=((temp*9/5)+32);
  document.getElementById("Kelvin").innerHTML=(parseInt(temp)+273);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Comment: No hay de queso, nomas de papa